# Can you trust the sample rate of a recording?

Tags: ableton-live, sample-rate

Say for example your DAW (in this case ableton live) was set to 96khz, but the macos settings for the capture device were set to 44.1khz.

Is there any chance the software would just spit out a file at the desired sample rate but with half the data? Or if the file has the right sample rate and sounds fine (i.e. not playing at double speed) that's enough to know it's ok?

If not, is there some way to inspect the file and check that it really has 96khz of information?

Comment: If you managed to make a recording with the settings you mentioned, in my experience the recording would have either terrible glitches, would play back at the wrong speed, or both. If it sounds good, then it is good. Whether your DAW will warn you about sample rates of files depends on your DAW.